# How to convert strings to UUID v4 in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uuid

Let's say I got a string below:

```js
const input = '83e54feeeb444c7484b3c7a81b5ba2fd';
```

My ideal output is an uuid v4:

```js
83e54fee-eb44-4c74-84b3-c7a81b5ba2fd
```

About the solution, I only come up with the idea:

```js
function insertString(str, index, value) {
    return str.substr(0, index) + value + str.substr(index);
}

function converToUUID(_uuid){
 _uuid = insertString(_uuid, 8, '-')
 _uuid = insertString(_uuid, 13, '-')
 _uuid = insertString(_uuid, 18, '-')
 _uuid = insertString(_uuid, 23, '-')
 
 return _uuid
}


console.log(converToUUID(a))
```

Is there a way to get the ideal output by not keep calling the `insertString` function?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex

```js
const input = '83e54feeeb444c7484b3c7a81b5ba2fd';
const output = input.replace(/(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})/g, '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5')
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const uuidRx = new RegExp(/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})([a-zA-Z0-9]{11})/);
const str = "83e54feeeb444c7484b3c7a81b5ba2fd";
const uuid = str.replace(uuidRx, "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");
console.log(uuid);
```